# Submitting form input after logging in with laravel

Tags: laravel

I have the view:

```
<form class="text-center" action="{{route('PostComment')}}" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" name="Comment" id="exampleTextarea" placeholder="Write down your thought here..." rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
</form>
```

And also the route:

```
Route::post('/Comment', [
'uses' => 'CommentController@Comment',
'as' => 'PostComment',
'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

And the controller(not so important):

```
public function Comment(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
    'Comment' => 'required|min:10|max:100',
    ]); // validation of comment

    $NewComment = new Comment();
    $NewComment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $NewComment->text = $request['Comment'];
    $NewComment->save();
    return redirect()->route('Debate');
}
```

My **question** is that when you submit the form data and you are not logged in, you have to log in but the form isn't submitted?(edited:using laravel auth)

How to make this thing work, you fill the textarea, you forgot to log in, you log in and the form is submited?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: 5.3, i am doing wrong something?

Comment: Good idea would be to not open the form till user logs in.